# How do I turn an Image into a matrix of colours?

Tags: haskell, monads

I’m playing with `Graphics.GD` and I’d like to read an image into a matrix of `Color` values, a bit like this:

```
rectFromImage :: Image -> IO [[Color]]
rectFromImage img = do
    size <- imageSize img
    return [[getPixel (x,y) img | x <- [1 .. fst size]] | y <- [1 .. snd size]]
```

Obviously, this does not work because `getPixel` returns `IO Color`, not `Color`:

```
Couldn't match type `IO Color' with `Foreign.C.Types.CInt'
Expected type: Color
  Actual type: IO Color
In the return type of a call of `getPixel'
In the expression: getPixel (x, y) img
In the expression: [getPixel (x, y) img | x <- [1 .. fst size]]
```

How do I “get rid of the IO” in the return of the `getPixel` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sequence` is the magic function you are looking for. `sequence` takes a list of IO actions and makes it an IO list of values. In type signature terms:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

Or, more specifically in your case:

```
sequence :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
```

So you can do, for example:

```
do
  putStrLn "Enter three lines of input:"
  irritatedUser <- sequence [getLine, getLine, getLine]
  putStrLn (irritatedUser !! 2)
```

and the last line the user writes will be printed back.

Anyway, in your case, this means you want to do

```
rectFromImage img = do
  size <- imageSize img
  sequence [sequence [getPixel (x,y) img | x <- [1 .. fst size]] | y <- [1 .. snd size]]
```

I snuck two `sequence` calls into there, to go from your `[[IO Color]]` to an `[IO [Color]]` and then on to an `IO [[Color]]`.

In general, you never "get rid of" the IO, you just propagate it upwards.